# Angular google maps not showing location which are in array

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-google-maps

I am trying to show locations on the map which is placed in the array using Angular google maps. Its working fine if I remove the coding of markers from component as well as from HTML. So I guess the issue should be in HTML page

```
export class MapviewComponent {
  zoom: number = 8;
  lat: number = 37.7919038;
  lng:number = -96.8651164 ;
   //Markers
   markers: marker[] = [{lat: 51.673858,lng: 7.815982},{lat: 51.373858,lng: 7.215982}] }
```

HTML coding

```
<agm-map
 [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [disableDefaultUI] = false
 [zoomControl] = "false"
 (mapClicked) = "mapClicked($event)">

  <agm-marker 
 *ngFor = "let m of  markers; let i = index"
 (markerClick) = "clickedMarker(m, i)"

  [latitude]="m.lat" 
  [longitude]="m.lng" 
  [label]="m.label"
  [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
  (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">
</agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: I'm [not able to reproduce](http://plnkr.co/edit/9DZ1yZgBBeiBswW3rrI4). Can you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell us what the problem is?

Comment: Same issue here, have you been able to solve it?